How to print last word in all lines irrespective of the length of each line?
I'm hoping to print only the last word in every line of my file as in the below example. I tried using awk 'print {$NF}'` but it doesn't give the output I like as not all lines are of the same length.
My file contains lines like the below
ID_1   ABC;GHI;JKKK;KLLL; 
ID_2   JKL;YUI;
ID_3   OPKJ;
ID_4   uncK;oPTY; 

and I wish to have output as below
KLLL
YUI
OPKJ
oPTY

I would appreciate it very much if you've got any ideas on how to accomplish the above on bash

It's impossible to be sure without a precise specification of what you mean by "the last word", but sed may be able to do what you want.  Try: sed 's/^.*[[:space:];]\(.*\);.*$/\1/' file.txt

You should show the work you did rather than ask folks to provide the answer without showing effort on your part.

I think you should start by defining, what is a word. You only give an example, but an example is not a definition. For instance, if the line does not contain any semicolon (example: :::::::::), is the "word" then the whole line?

Did you include the [python] and [r] tags by mistake?

What have you tried? https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - Show what you did so people can help explain why it didn't work, as that both helps solve your problem and provides examples for the next person.

grep -Po '\w+(?=\W*$)' file

1) awk 1 Place this in mathew.awk.  The first sub removes the final ; in $2 and the second sub removes everything up to the last ; remaining in $2 and finally print $2.
{ sub(/;[[:space:]]*$/, "", $2); sub(/.*;/,"",$2); print $2 }

and then run it with the following where mathew.dat is the data file.
awk -f mathew.awk mathew.dat

2) awk 2 An alternative is the following.  First split $0 into fields where spaces and/or semicolons are separators and then print the field before the last.
awk -F"[[:space:];]+" "{print $(NF-1)}" mathew.dat

3) R In R read the data, take the second column, trim off junk at the end of the lines, remove everything up to the last ; and write it back out.
"mathew.dat" |>
  read.table() |>
  _$V2 |>
  trimws(whitespace = "[;[:space:]]") |>
  sub(".*;", "", x = _) |>
  writeLines()

4) qsv  The qsv utility (releases) is available for Linux, Mac and Windows.  squeeze runs of whitespace down to a single space, trim whitespace off ends and replace remaining whitespace with semicolons, insert empty semicolon separated fields after the first field giving 20 fields and then pick off field 19.  20 can be replaced with any number equal or greater than the largest number of fields in any row after spaces are replaced with semicolons and 19 can then be replaced with one less.  Below we have used the Windows ^ continuation character but if on Linux use backslash instead.
qsv apply -n operations squeeze,trim,replace 1 ^
   --comparand " " --replacement ; mathew.dat | ^
qsv fixlengths -d; -i1 -l20 | ^
qsv select 19

5) choose  The choose utility is similar in purpose to cut but also supports negative fields numbered from the end. This extracts the second field (which is referred to as 1 since it is zero based) and then from that selects the last semicolon separated field.
It seems to ignore the empty field at the end.
choose 1 < mathew.dat | choose -f ; -1

Update
Add (2) and simplify.
Add (3).
Add (4) and simplify.
Deal with tabs as suggested in comments by @Ed Morton.
Add (5)

This was my first thought, but you beat me to it. :)

I like alternative 2 (nice to know that you can specify a regex as a field separator!)

awk is great for that sort of thing.

I'd bet money the white space in the OPs example is intended to be tabs, not blanks - if you make the blanks in the 2nd awk script [:space:] instead then it'll work either way.

Good idea. Have added.

A Python script to do this would be:
with open('path/to/file.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line.strip(';\n').rsplit(';',1)[-1])

If you want it to take a filename as and input, create a Python file with the following content (maybe call it print_last.py):
import argparse

def print_last(file_path: str):
    with open('path/to/file.txt') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            print(line.strip(';\n').rsplit(';',1)[-1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Prints last word')
    parser.add_argument('file_path', help='path to the file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print_last(args.file_path)

Then call it via:
$ python3 print_last.py ~/path/to/file.txt


A couple of options. Firstly with a "double split" and secondly with a regular expression, using Python:
import re

FILE = "foo.txt"
P = re.compile(r"(\w+);")

with open(FILE) as foo:
    for line in foo:
        print(line.split()[-1].split(";")[-2])

with open(FILE) as foo:
    for line in foo:
        print(P.findall(line)[-1])


Not the most elegant, but should work:
tr -s ';' file.txt | rev | grep -Eo '^.[^;]*' | tr -d ';' | rev

It compresses a run of semicolons to a single one.
We end up with lines which has zero or one semicolon at the end.
We reverse each line.
We now have zero or one semicolon at the start of each line.
We take the first character of each line (which could be a semicolon) and the subsequent non-semicolon characters of each line.
If there was a semicolon at the start, we remove it.
We reverse each line back.

In sed -
$: sed -E 's/.*[ ;]([^ ;]+)[; ]*$/\1/' file
KLLL
YUI
OPKJ
oPTY

In case a bare bash solution helps -
$: while IFS="$IFS;" read -ra f; do echo "${f[-1]}"; done < file
KLLL
YUI
OPKJ
oPTY

$: while read -r line;do line=${line%;}; echo ${line##*[ ;]}; done < file
KLLL
YUI
OPKJ
oPTY

$: pat=$'([^ ;]+)[; ]+$'; while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ $pat ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; done < file
KLLL
YUI
OPKJ
oPTY

Your problem is just that the semicolon at the end of the line is delimiting an extra field, but one of your lines only has one field after the ID column - you have to count both the whitespace after the first column and the semicolons as delimiters, and take the next to last if you are splitting into fields, or just manually account for it with string processing.

Since you already know how each line looks like in your file. I think the you can simply use str.split() method. It results in a list with elements separated by a delimiter.
with open("<your_text_file.txt>") as file:
   for line in file:
      print(line.split()[-1].split(";")[-2])

This will result in:
KLLL
YUI
OPKJ
oPTY


Explanation:
Now what is going here is:
line.split()

is taking each line, separate it by a whitespace, resulting in:
['ID_1', 'ABC;GHI;JKKK;KLLL;']
['ID_2', 'JKL;YUI;']
['ID_3', 'OPKJ;']
['ID_4', 'uncK;oPTY;']

There are two elements each line, but the text you need is found in the 2nd element, so we take the last element from each list line.split()[-1]. This results in as follows:
ABC;GHI;JKKK;KLLL;
JKL;YUI;
OPKJ;
uncK;oPTY;

now we can treat this as a string again, and use split with the delimeter ;. Continuing our command:
line.split()[-1].split(";")

This results in the following:
['JKL', 'YUI', '']
['OPKJ', '']
['uncK', 'oPTY', '']

Notice that the texts you need are the 2nd last element of each list. So we can extract that using line.split()[-1].split(";")[-2]. This results in:
KLLL
YUI
OPKJ
oPTY

